# Putting info from multiple tabs into a master tab no matter the quantity or name of the contributing tab(s) (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have seven columns (CD, CE, CF, CG, CH, Ci, and CJ). This same format reoccurrs across multiple tabs within my sheet. Right now there are only three or four of these identically formatted tabs, but over time more will be created, each having the same type of data in the same seven columns, in the same place.

I want to create a "master" tab, in which all the data from all of the other tabs is aggregated into one master sheet. These columns are A,B,C,D,E,F, and G.

For example if tab1 has 3 entries, tab2 has 2, and tab3 has 5, the master tab should have 10 entries listed.

Please note that I can't just specify a specific range from which to source the data, since I don't know how many of these identical source tabs will be created over time or what they will be named. It needs to seek out those specific columns (CD-CJ) across all tabs that exist in the sheet, and put them together in the mater no matter the tab. Note that CD-CJ will only contain data that should participate in being aggregated into the master.

As far as I can tell, this might require a google apps script.

RESOLVED: Please see both Century Tuna's and my answer!

Comment: Are you able to change how the data gets recorded into the sheet? I ask because we see these sorts of aggregation questions a lot and—if this is something that’s in your control—it’s usually much easier to have all the data directly recorded in a “master” tab, because then it becomes trivial to create as many tabs as you want with whatever filtered cuts of the master data you need, without having to work backwards to compile. If that’s not an option in this case then ignore everything above :)

Comment: I would love to be able to do it that way, but for my use case there is a lot complication within each tab (budgets, types of budget, order and tag of the budget, etc). It's for budgeting individual films within a company's master accounting. All of that above mentioned crap, format differing from tab to tab depending on the film, goes to the range I want to pull from per tab which is pretty much the only consistent format between all the individual films tabs. That then gets pulled from and adds up in the master sheet accounting all the films the company handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Try this sample implementation, but this needs to be changed based on the current structure of your sheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var mastersheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master"); //Indicate the master sheet name here
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets(); 
  var alldata = []; 

  sheets.forEach(x => {

    if(x.getSheetName() != "Master"){ //Make sure that the master sheet name is included here to exclude from the iteration

    var data = x.getRange(2,3, x.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();
    alldata.push(data); 
    
    }
  })

  var finaldata = alldata.flat(); 
  mastersheet.getRange(2,1, finaldata.length, 7).setValues(finaldata);

}
```

Take note that `var data = x.getRange(2,3, x.getLastRow() - 1, 7)` getRange values is referenced by row number and column number as indicated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns), so in your case get the numerical position of `CD` as the starting column and 7 as the number of columns.

`x.getLastRow()` is used as `numRows` in order to fetch the last row on each sheet.

Sample sheets (All data used are just samples):

Sheet2
[image]
Sheet3
[image]
Sheet4
[image]

Master sheet when the script is run:

[image]

Comment: Resolved - see my post! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Century Tuna's code worked very well. The issue I was having was that it did not tolerate additional columns (not pertinent to the dataset) that had rows extending below the number of rows for my range. For example, if my range has 4 rows of data (like Century Tuna's example) but another column in the tab has 100, in the master sheet it would spit out the 4 rows of data, then 96 blank rows, and then move on to indexing the next tab. The fix for this was to use a filter method.

Here's the new code with the filter fix. Note that the only other difference is that the start column for my source data is 82.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mastersheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var finaldata = [];

  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (sheet.getSheetName() !== "Master") {
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var startColumn = 82; // Starting column index
      var numColumns = lastColumn - startColumn + 1; // Calculate the number of columns to include
      if (numColumns > 0) {
        var data = sheet.getRange(2, startColumn, lastRow - 1, numColumns).getValues();
        data = data.filter(row => row.join("").trim() !== ""); // Exclude empty rows
        finaldata = finaldata.concat(data); // Concatenate data arrays
      }
    }
  });

  if (finaldata.length > 0) {
    mastersheet.clear(); // Clear existing data in the master sheet
    mastersheet.getRange(2, 1, finaldata.length, finaldata[0].length).setValues(finaldata);
  }
}
```